# Collision detection between non-linear objects

Tags: vectors, 3d, classical-mechanics

I'm trying to do collision detection between two non linear objects that are moving in curve or non linear movement. how would one do that. I did it using linear movement, but I don't know the equation of two non linear objects.

```
double collision() // returns t>=0 the collision time or -1 if no collision
    {
    int i;
    double t,dt;
    double x,y,z,d0,d1;
    dt=_max_t;
    x=pos0[0]-pos1[0];
    y=pos0[1]-pos1[1];
    z=pos0[2]-pos1[2];
    d0=sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z));
    x=pos0[0]-pos1[0]+(vel0[0]-vel1[0])*dt;
    y=pos0[1]-pos1[1]+(vel0[1]-vel1[1])*dt;
    z=pos0[2]-pos1[2]+(vel0[2]-vel1[2])*dt;
    d1=sqrt((x*x)+(y*y)+(z*z));
    if (d0<=_max_d) return  0.0; // collided now
    if (d0<=d1)     return -1.0; // never collide
    t=(_max_d-d0)*dt/(d1-d0);
    return t;
    }
```

Comment: We need the dynamics of the system to derive the Equations of Motion for both bodies to be able to help you any further.

Comment: @gunbl4d3 What kind of dynamics exactly ? I have the velocity, positions

Comment: To derive the equations of motion you need the forces involved in the system. For instance if there are no forces the two bodies can only move in a straight line with their initial velocity (which is the case you seem to have above).

Comment: @gunbl4d3 Thanks for the answer. The problem is I'm simulating a flight with ships collision detection. but the ships move in non linear way with different altitude over the time. but I don't have the forces that impact in non linear way

Comment: So what you are trying to accomplish is to compute **if** there is a collision given the positions of two objects at a given time snapshot? Because if you are trying to simulate some unknown dynamics it will be impossible to derive the equations of motion to "predict" the evolution of their position in time. For instance, how are the positions of the ships updated in time in your simulation? Is it some game in which players control them? Is it some kind of group dynamics algorithm?

Comment: If you by colliding meaning the surfaces of the objects meet at some point in time, then you will need some mathematical description of the surface of your objects to be able to calculate if they collide.

Comment: @gunbl4d3 I want to computer if there is a collision given the positions of two objects at a given time snapshot, with their velocities too. its in game physics

Comment: @andre you don't need the velocities for a given time snapshot to compute collisions. Just check if the distance between the two objects is smaller than a collision threshold at each time snapshot. Just beware that this threshold has to be greater than the distance the objects travel between time intervals so as to look realistic.

Comment: @gunbl4d3 I need the time of collision too

Comment: @andre the time of collision will be the time at which the snapshot triggers the collision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each time $t$, you have the positions of the two objects $(x_{p_1}(t),y_{p_1}(t),z_{p_1}(t))$ and $(x_{p_2}(t),y_{p_2}(t),z_{p_2}(t))$

Compute the distance between the two objects as $$d(t)=\sqrt{(x_{p_1}(t)-x_{p_2}(t))^2+(y_{p_1}(t)-y_{p_2}(t))^2+(z_{p_1}(t)-z_{p_2}(t))^2}$$

Then define a collision threshold, $d_{col}$.

The collision condition is therefore, for each time $t$,
 $$d(t)<d_{col}.$$

That is, if the above inequality holds we have a collision at time $t$, else, we don't.

Just make sure the time interval at which you check this condition and the value of $d_{col}$ are appropriate for the problem to look realistic.

**Edit: C Implementation**

```
//assumes both p1 and p2 have the same size 
unsigned int collision(double* p1, double* p2, unsigned int size, double dcol){ 
    double d, sum=0;
    unsigned int i;

    for( i=0; i<size; i++){
        sum+=(p1[i]-p2[i])*(p1[i]-p2[i]);  
    }
    d=sqrt(sum);

    if( d<dcol ) return 1; //collision produced
    else return 0; // no collision
}

//main flow of the algorithm
int main(){

    //Initialize the position vectors p1 and p2
    double p1={0,0,0}, p2={1,1,1};
    double t=0, dt=0.01, dcol=0.01; //set dt and dcol to whatever fits you

    while(1){
         updatePositions(...); //function that updates the positions of the objects
         if(collision(p1,p2,3,dcol)==1) break;
         else {t=t+dt;}
    }
    printf("Collision produced at t=%lf\n",t);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you derive the collision formula in the above code

Comment: Reworded my answer for clarity.

Comment: Sorry but I meant the code in my post. I would like to know the derivation of it.

Comment: You just have to check the condition I stated in my answer each time you update the positions of the objects, to see if any of them collided during the update. You need no other formula.

Comment: what is xp(t) expressed as ?

Comment: can you show some pseudo code in any language you prefer ?

Comment: The $x_{p_i}(t)$ means just to take the x coordinate of the object $i$ at time $t$. It's your pos0[0] and pos1[0].

Comment: but where is the time of collision ?

Comment: You have to check this condition **every time t** that you update the positions of the objects. Thus the time of the collision is the time t at which the check returns 1.

Comment: so just make a dt = 0.01; then increment it, while checking the collision and when it returns true, then this is the time of collision ?

Comment: Define a value for dt and dcol. At t=0 compute the positions of both objects, then check if there is a collision. If there is your collision is at time t=0, if there is not increment t=t+dt. Compute the positions at t+dt and check if there is a collision. If there is your collision is at time t+dt, if not rinse and repeat.

Comment: I got it, can you show some pseudo code please for the incremental. I'm beginner

Comment: Added a squematic of the main flow of the algorithm and how should the collision part be introduced.

Comment: Thanks so much thanks a lot

Comment: the time is increasing, I would like to set a min time, so that the collision of time should occur and decrease the time

Comment: I am assuming this is a game,as stated in the comments above (hence the infinite loop), and no collision could occur in a finite amount of time.